# Rails model to recursive json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a Menu model, that has submenus of same type. Something like:

- level 1

  - level 1.1
  - level 1.2
- level 2

  - level 2.1
  - ...

So, I need a way to include in my json, all levels, in a recursive way.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please explain what you'd like to do in more detail? If all you want to do is convert an ActiveRecord record to JSON, just call `to_json` on it. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Comment: Same here. How is this data stored? What kind of data structure do you use? If it's in a hash, then you can just cal to_json as max_w says (This would work recursively). Otherwise you can most likely use something like .map() or .collect() to get it in some form on which you can use to_json. But we would need to know more details to show you how this could be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON in Rails works through two methods:

`as_json` is responsible for creating a hash representation of the object whereas `to_json` converts that hash object representation to JSON.

So what you need to do is define the as_json method in your model to include what you want.

```
def as_json
 {
   :other_options => value,
   :submenu => self.submenus.collect { |n| n.as_json }
 }
end
```

This is a very crude implementation, but it will recursively visit all submenus (as submenus are menus themselves) and render them to a Hash that then gets translated to JSON.

Comment: nice simple explanation of as_json vs to_json